# Select rows which have the following values

Tags: mysql

Need help with a select query. I have a DB which stores invoice items. So an invoice can have multiple items.

```
id   invoice_id    product_id
1     123            1
2     123            2
3     123            3
4     123            5  
5     124            1      
6     124            2
```

What I need is a query that returns all invoices that have product_id equal to 1,2,3.
Meaning if invoice 123 has products 1,2,3 and 5 return it also, but it must contain atleast 1,2,3

So the query should only return the first 4 rows because invoice# 123 has products 1,2,3 regardless of what other products it may have

```
id   invoice_id    product_id
1     123            1
2     123            2
3     123            3
4     123            5
```

Comment: Please update your question with the query that you currently have and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return all `invoice_ids` that have products 1, 2 and 3, then you will want to look at using a HAVING clause similar to the following:

```
select invoice_id
from yourtable
where product_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by invoice_id
having count(distinct product_id) >= 3
```

Using a WHERE clause filter you can return those with the product_id's that you need (1, 2, 3) but then adding a HAVING clause you will add another filter to return those rows with a distinct count of product id's greater than 3.

If you then want to return all of the details you can use the following query to get the result:

```
select id, invoice_id, product_id
from yourtable
where invoice_id in (select invoice_id
                     from yourtable
                     where product_id in (1, 2, 3)
                     group by invoice_id
                     having count(distinct product_id) >= 3);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e887/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to select the invoice ID's that contain the products you're interested in, then use the results of this to select the same invoice ID's along with ALL of the products associated with those ID's:

```
SELECT id, invoice_id, productid 
FROM invoices 
WHERE invoice_id IN (SELECT invoice_id 
                     FROM invoices 
                     WHERE product_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
                     GROUP BY invoice_id)
```